# assign frequency as new column in r

Tags: r, frequency

Let's say I have the following string:

```
a <- c("a", "b", "c", "b", "a", "a", "e")
b <- table(a)
```

b gives me the frequency of every element in a. How do I create a dataframe with two columns, the first column is a and in the second I have the frequency of each element?

The output should look like this:

```
f <- c(3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1)
output <- data.frame(a,f)
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 3):

We can use `add_count` to create a new column

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
tibble(a) %>% 
     add_count(a)
```

---

Or in `base R` with `ave`

```
data.frame(a, freq = ave(seq_along(a), a, FUN = length))
```

---

Or if it needs to be from 'b', do the match with the names of 'b' and the vector 'a' to expand the `table` output and then convert the `table` object to data.frame with `as.data.frame`

```
as.data.frame(b[a])
#  a Freq
#1 a    3
#2 b    2
#3 c    1
#4 b    2
#5 a    3
#6 a    3
#7 e    1
```

Answer (score 2):

Using merge:

`merge(as.data.frame(a), as.data.frame(table(a)))`

```
#  a Freq
#1 a    3
#2 a    3
#3 a    3
#4 b    2
#5 b    2
#6 c    1
#7 e    1
```